# How do I post data from react server to express server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to pass user data (email and password) to my express server to implement logging in. What is the problem in my code? I keep getting this error: "Request failed with status code 400". I have added proxy to client package.json like this: "proxy": "http://localhost:5000".

Code in React component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import axios from 'axios'

class SigningPage extends Component {
    state = {
        signInEmail: '',
        signInPassword: ''
    }

    handleInputChange = (e) => {

        this.setState({

            [e.target.name]: e.target.value

        });

    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/login';

        const user = {
            email: this.state.signInEmail, 
            password: this.state.signInPassword
        }

        axios.post(url, user).then((res) => {

            console.log(res)

        }).catch((e) => {

            console.log(e)

        });

    }

    render() {

    return <div>

                    <article>
                        <h1>Sign in</h1>
                        <form action="/login" method="post"onChange={this.handleInputChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <input 
                                name="signInEmail" 
                                type="email" 
                                placeholder="email"
                                required>
                            </input>
                            <input 
                                name="signInPassword" 
                                type="password" 
                                placeholder="password"
                                required>
                            </input>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit form"}>
                        </form>
                    </article>
                </div>
```

Code in express server

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const path = require('path')

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const db = mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://*****:**********@cluster0-ldqwn.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({ email: String, password: String }); 

const MyModel = mongoose.model('Userss', UserSchema);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.post('/userSignUp', async (req, res)=>{

    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt()
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)
        const userData = {email: req.body.email, password: hashedPassword}
        MyModel.findOne(userData)
        .then(exUs =>{
            if(exUs){
                console.log('exists')
            } else {
                new MyModel(userData).save(
                    (err, user) => {if (err) 
                        {return console.error(err)} else {
                            console.log(user.email + " saved to bookstore collection.")}
                        }
                    )

            }          
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    } catch {
        res.status(500).send()
    }

})

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await MyModel.findOne({email: req.body.email})
.then(exUs => {return exUs})

    if (user == null) {
        return res.status(400).send('no user')
    }

    try{
        if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)){
            res.send('succ')
        } else {
            res.send('not succ')
        }
    } catch {
        res.status(500).send()
    }

})
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not coming from here: `return res.status(400).send('no user')` in your `/login` endpoint?

Comment: Yes, it was coming from there. The problem was in CORS policy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in CORS policy.